# LINQ statment looks unreasonable to me: what's my error?

Tags: c#, asp.net, linq, asp.net-identity

There has to be a better way:

```
public IList<ApplicationUser> GetProspects()
        {
            var UsrNames = Roles.GetUsersInRole("prospect");
            IList<ApplicationUser> Users = new List<ApplicationUser>();

            foreach ( var u in UsrNames)
            {
                // In theory should return at most one element. 
                var UserListFromQuery = from usr in (new ApplicationDbContext()).Users where usr.UserName == u select usr;
                Users.Add(UserListFromQuery.ElementAtOrDefault(0));
            }
            return Users;
        }
```

Can you please show me the error of my ways?

Comment: What are you trying to accomplish?

Comment: `what's my error?` <= Usually you have an error you want to share with us, I think it's odd that we should have to guess the error in your code? If you are looking for a code review then you should post on the code review se.

Comment: No, the code has no errors, but there has to be an error in my thinking because surely there is a better way. This seems very botched and I am fairly certain I am missing something obvious.

Comment: What I am trying to do is to load all users that have a certain role. I have explored the various similar SO questions but the other answers either didn't fit or pointed out details that in my case are correct. One for example said to make sure that System.Linq was in the using clause, which it is. It just seems so weird that this would be the correct solution. I can't believe that it is, I must be missing something that is obvious to people with LINQ experience (therefore not me).

Comment: I'm not terribly familiar with linq against a db, but yeah, what you are accomplishing can typically be accomplished in one line, like `return allUsers.Where((o) => userNames.Contains(o.Name)).ToList();` or if userNames is not a List `return allUsers.Where((o) => userNames.Any((un) => un == o.Name)).ToList();`

Comment: In a loop, like you have, you would just do `var appUser = allUsers.FirstOrDefault((o) => o.Name == un);` And then if appUser isn't null (the "default" value), you add it to your list. (`un` is your username variable, or `u` in your code)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should do what you want:

```
using (var context = new ApplicationDbContext())
{
    var result = Roles.GetUsersInRole("prospect")
                      .Select(name => context.Users.FirstOrDefault(user => user.UserName == name))
                      .Where(user => user != null)
                      .ToList();
}
```

I've modified your code to utilize a `using` statement for the context, so as to ensure it is disposed of properly even if there is an exception. Then I have a linq query which does the following:

1. Get the usernames
2. For every username, select the first user in `Users` with a matching username
3. Remove all `null`s from the resulting enumeration. This is necessary because `FirstOrDefault` returns `null` if no matching user is found
4. Turn our final enumeration into a List

Comment: I think you forgot `ToList()`.

Comment: @NetMage Good catch.

Comment: HA! See? I was certain there had to be a goddamn better way :) Putting this in now, thanks :) This looks A LOT cleaner.

Answer (score 1):

I guess you could join it, then group it, then cull the grouping. I'm not sure whether there is an overall advantage of the front-loading that you'd be doing by joining and grouping, so you might want to put a stopwatch to this (and to your original code) and figure that one out.

My suggestion is:

```
// force a prefetch, rather than potentially slamming the server again and again
var allUsers = (new ApplicationDbContext()).Users.ToList(); 

// use the prefetched list to join & filter on
var result = from entitled in UsrNames 
          join user in allUsers
          on entitled equals user.UserName
          group user by user.UserName into grp
          select grp.First();

return result.ToList();
```

*Couple of thoughts:*
This is clearly a user-related table. So I'm guessing that you're not going to have 100k records or something along that scale. At most, maybe thousands. So safe to cache in local memory, especially if the data will not change many times throughout the day. If this is true, you might even want to preload the collection earlier on, and store into a singular instance of the data, to be reused later on. But this observation would only hold true if the data changes very infrequently.